# How can I disable the global menu in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, appmenu

I can't open bookmarks in new tabs from it (this seems to be a [bug in Unity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/globalmenu-extension/+bug/748850)), so I disabled the add-on for it. But the latest update for Firefox (22.0) removed that add-on and re-enabled the global menu. How can I disable it again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just updated to Firefox 22.0 under Ubuntu 12.04 / Unity. The add-on is indeed gone.

There is a config setting that appears to disable the (tremendously annoying) global menus.

Open firefox.

Enter `about:config` in the address bar (like you're trying to go to that URL as a website).

Use the Search field to find the `use_unity_menubar` setting.

Right-click on it. Choose `TOGGLE` on the popup dialog. That should turn off the global menus and restore the top-of-window menus. (The full name of the preference is `ui.use_unity_menubar`.)

Comment: My pleasure. Sure wish they would stop screwing around and use the 'standard' mechanism. I find the global menus very annoying and a hindrance to my productivity.

Comment: Since I installed 12.04 two months ago this >exact< problem has been bugging me....I googled and googled and read post after post...until I tried the above solution. AAAhhhh...what a relief!!! Man, many thanks to both the asker and @Art Swri