# Alt Key for HUD Doesn't Work

Tags: unity, hud

After few of tweakings, I doesn't have HUD anymore.

Normally (on another computer):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se1Uz.png]

But it doesn't appear at all (on my computer):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mSammyt.png]

Indeed, **the ALT key call the menu of focused app**. So, as the consequences:

- I can't do Alt+Tab Windows Switching
- I can't call Unity command prompt (Alt+F2)

Note: but I still can call Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T).

My HUD service was on:

```
prompt # locate hud | grep usr | grep service
/usr/lib/indicator-appmenu/hud-service
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.canonical.hud.service
prompt #
```

I have set HUD shortcut again on System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcut > HUD and Alt L. But the problem still exist. It is annoying problem that doesn't solved by just **unity --replace** or **unity --reset** or by reinstalling *indicator-appmenu* (I've done them all, times). I have read some questions about similiar topic but no one same with this. Any help will be very appreciated.

### **EDITED (by myself)**

I have upgraded **ubuntu-indicator-applet** (`sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu-tools`), but problem still exists.

Thank you.

Comment: You may be able to restore things by opening Compiz-Config-Settings-Manager. Find the button for "Unity Plug In". On the first page "General" is a setting for "Key to show the HUD when tapped". If you don't have CCSM, install it with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.

Comment: Thank you. But I have set ALT for HUD n the CCSM too. The problem still exist.

Comment: Any new other suggestion? The problem is same until this June.

Comment: Is there any suggestion at this October?

Comment: Yes, my **Key To Show The HUD** is **Alt L** in there. I have removed also ~/.compiz-1 and ~/config/compiz-1. The strange condition is in the new user account I created, the HUD and all Unity aspects are normal. And I have rebooted many times. Problem still exists at my user. Any other suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/312965/how-can-i-disable-the-global-menu-in-firefox