# alt key for HUD conflict

Tags: shortcuts, hud

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and encountered a weird problem

When I am using google-chrome, I use Alt+D to go to the address bar and type a url. However, every times I press Alt, Ubuntu HUD will pop up and block my chrome. So I need to press Alt again to get rid of it.

P.S.
 I do not have the problems using Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Are you on a virtual machine? I am on 14.04 and use alt+d to navigate to the URL bar.

Comment: @Jobin real machine, desktop version. If you press alt key alone, will you get HUD?

Comment: See alse http://askubuntu.com/questions/312965/how-can-i-disable-the-global-menu-in-firefox

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a slight change in the behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd> this time; tapping <kbd>Alt</kbd> will bring out the HUD.  Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> will bring the application's menu.

If you quickly tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> you will see your cursor jump to Chrome's address bar, and then the HUD appears right over it (annoying).

If you *hold down* <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then press <kbd>D</kbd>, you should see the cursor go to Chrome's address bar.

In other words, you have to slow down to make it do what you want.

If you don't care about the HUD, you can go into Settings > Keyboard and change the shortcut or disable the shortcut there

[image]

Comment: is it possible to go back what i have in Ubuntu 13.10 ?

Comment: Unfortunately - without a patch - I don't think you can.  I myself have opted to disable the HUD since Alt is such an important keystroke for so many applications.  Until a better answer comes along.

Comment: Their is also a bug report related to this annoying behavior: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1287798

Comment: I can't believe this bug is since 2014 /facepalm