# Prevent Alt from highlighting menu bar

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, inkscape

There are tons of questions related to disabling default behavior of `Alt+<some key>` in Ubuntu. My problem, however, is a little different. Whenever the `Alt` key is pressed, it triggers the menu bar selection (with the action letter underlined). While this is great in general, in Inkscape it leads to a lot of  problems.

Please note that my question is not related to HUD or Unity bar. It's a global behavior no matter which application I'm running. How can I disable the action related to `pressing Alt key only` in Inkscape only (best case) or if that isn't possible, everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run command ccsm in terminal (If you don't have that installed, it will show).
Go to Desktop → Ubuntu Unity Plugin and change the "Key to show the menu bar while pressed".

Source: [How to stop Alt from triggering Global Menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455519/how-to-stop-alt-from-triggering-global-menu)